# Jacoco doesn't include spring cloud contract generated test sources

Tags: jacoco, spring-cloud-contract, producer

I am using spring cloud contract at producer side to verified the contract and it did automatically generate test sources under /build/generated-test-sources. However when I run jacoco code coverage report, the generated-test-source is not included in the report. Looking for some work around to include that in jacoco report, did not get any luck. Does anyone know how to include a spring cloud contract verifier generated-test-source into jacoco report?

the below is what I have in my build.gradle.

```
jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination file("${buildDir}/jacocoHtml")
    }
}
```